# How wait reacquire the lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, concurrency, producer-consumer

I am referring the producer-consumer example from this [site](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2015/07/how-to-use-wait-notify-and-notifyall-in.html)

In both producer and consumer code, **wait** is wrapped inside loop which is inturn wrapped inside **synchronized** block.

But once **wait** is returned i.e. from while loop, I don't how the thread is reacquiring the lock because adding/removing the item from the queue is still inside the synchronized block.

Also I feel we might need two different locks i.e. one for consumer and one for producer instead of locking the whole queue. Because I feel at any time either consumer/producer can work on the queue.

Please let me know if my understanding is wrong. Also it will be great if someone can provide the example with two different locks.

Comment: `wait` releases the lock, waits for somebody to call `notify()`, and then joins a thundering herd to reacquire it. It all happens internally. You don't need to know *how* it happens, you only need to know *that* it happens. Your second question is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

> But once wait is returned i.e. from while loop, I don't how the thread
>   is reacquiring the lock because adding/removing the item from the
>   queue is still inside the synchronized block.

- Thread (producer or consumer) stucks in line `queue.wait();`without progressing, until that thread acquires the lock.
- Once it acquires the lock, it will start to progress, go out from the while loop and progress till `queue.notifyAll();`. From `queue.notifyAll();`, it releases the lock. So that other thread can acquire that.

> Also I feel we might need two different locks i.e. one for consumer
>   and one for producer instead of locking the whole queue. Because I
>   feel at any time either consumer/producer can work on the queue.

It is true that ***either one of can work on the queue AT THE SAME TIME***. But we ***need only one lock***. The reason is we have ***only one scared resource*** (queue). So having a lock for that scared resource will make sure only one can work on that at the same time.

Hope you understand the points. :))